# How do you login with node-irc?

Tags: node.js, irc

It is extremely easy to setup and it works fine. But nowhere in the documentation does it say how to

```
/msg nickserv identify <pword>
```

The closest I could find was

```
client.join('#yourchannel yourpass');
```

or maybe

```
For any commands that there aren’t methods for you can use the send() method which sends raw messages to the server
client.send('MODE', '#yourchannel', '+o', 'yournick');
```

but neither seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`client.say("nickserv", "identify <pword>");` doesn't work? The [API](https://node-irc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API.html) says it should.

Comment: i wish i could help like people like you do. but these arent rookie questions.

Comment: Most questions here are difficult only because (I suspect) the questioner has been banging their proverbial head against the proverbial wall for so long, they can't see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand answer above, the only way I found so far to really know when the client is fully connected, is using then `autoConnect: false` mode upon creation:

```
var client = new irc.Client('irc.freenode.net', 'CommandBot', {
  autoConnect: false
});
client.connect(retryCount, function(serverReply) {
  console.log("Connected!\n", serverReply);
  client.join('#channel', function(input) {
    console.log("Joined #channel");
    client.say('#channel', "Hi, madafaca");
  });
});
```