# Auth to NickServ via Node.js IRC

Tags: javascript, node.js, irc

How can I log in to NickServ in Node.js with IRC module?

I have tried using NickServ module, this is the reply (my nick is in a group):

```
error:  { prefix: 'irc.cccp-project.net',
  server: 'irc.cccp-project.net',
  command: 'err_notregistered',
  rawCommand: '451',
  commandType: 'error',
  args: [ '*', 'Register first.' ] }
```

Using IRC module:

```
bot.say("nickserv", "identify " + password);

error:  { prefix: 'irc.cccp-project.net',
      server: 'irc.cccp-project.net',
      command: 'err_notregistered',
      rawCommand: '451',
      commandType: 'error',
      args: [ '*', 'Register first.' ] }
```

I also tried [How do you login with node-irc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596110/how-do-you-login-with-node-irc#)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see your error:
http://www.mirc.org/mishbox/reference/rawhelp4.htm#raw451

You have to wait to join a channel until your client is fully connected. A solution is that you tell the constructor to join your channel:

```
var irc = require('irc');
var client = new irc.Client('irc.yourserver.com', 'myNick', {
    channels: ['#channel'],
});
```

from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/irc

Comment: I know that the question was asked a year ago. But i had the exact same error and found this post. So maybe it helps someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided by @Kyroy works, the actual thing you need to hook on is the `registered` event:

```
var irc = require('irc');
var client = new irc.Client('irc.yourserver.com', 'myNick');
client.addListener('registered', function() {
    client.say('nickserv', 'identify ' + password);
})
```